# Project Euler #35 : Reason for the incomplete output in my solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, output

[Problem 35, Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=35) The output of my solution stops at a rather odd point for reasons beyond my current understanding. I have followed along with the code on paper and it seems right to me.

```py
prime_list =[]
prime2 = []
prime2_up=[]
##The sieve of eratosthenes##c
def prime_sieve(n):
    prime = [True for i in range(0,n+1)]
    p = 2
    while p*p<=n:
        if prime[p] == True:
            for i in range(p*p,n+1,p):
                prime[i] = False
        p+=1
    for p in range(2,n):
        if prime[p]:
            prime_list.append(p)
##Check whether the given prime is circular or not##
def circular_checker():
    for j in prime_list:
        x = str(j)
        for i in range(0,len(x)):
            x = x[i:len(x)]+x[0:i]
            if int(x) not in prime_list:
                return False
        prime2.append(int(x))
##Function To remove duplicates and sort the list##
def remove_duplicate():
    for k in prime2:
        if k not in prime2_up:
            prime2_up.append(k)
            prime2_up.sort()

prime_sieve(1000)
circular_checker()
remove_duplicate()

print(prime2_up)
```

I expect the output to be a list of circular primes upto 1000, but the list abruptly stops at 19.

the output:
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 31, 71]

Please explain, with relevant reasons, the flaw in my solution.

### EDIT 1

Thanks for the helpful replies by @khelwood and @dollarAkshay . But now I face a new problem of over counting.
The number of circular primes indicated by the updated code is 121. This is indeed wrong.

```py
##updated part, also the exclusion of numbers with digits 2,4,6,8,0 and 5 to reduce runtime##
def circular_checker():
    for j in prime_list:
        x = str(j)
        circular = True
        for i in range(0,len(x)):
            x = x[i:len(x)]+x[0:i]
            if not prime[int(x)] or "2" in x or "4" in x or "6" in x or "8" in x or "0" in x or "5" in x:
                circular = False
                break
        if circular:
            prime2.append(int(x))

prime_sieve(1000000)
circular_checker()
prime2_up.append(2)
prime2_up.append(5)
remove_duplicate()

print(len(prime2_up))
```

Comment: What is the next circular prime supposed to be?

Comment: There should be 13, 17 but as you ask the next one is 79

Comment: you can remove duplicates by just making a set of it: `prime2_up = list(sorted(set(prime2)))`, or better yet, just use a set from the beginning

Comment: @khelwood `The number, 197, is called a circular prime because all rotations of the digits: 197, 971, and 719, are themselves prime.`

Comment: Your `circular_checker` has a return false in the middle of the loop. That exits your whole loop, so no more primes will be checked after that.

Comment: reason for down votes, please?

Comment: `int(x) not in prime_list` is super slow.  You should save the seive and check `prime[int(x)]` instead

Answer (score 2):

Your `circular_checker` has a return false in the middle of the loop. That exits your whole loop, so no more primes will be checked after that.

Fix that by not returning partway through your loop.

```
def circular_checker():
    for j in prime_list:
        x = str(j)
        circular = True
        for i in range(0,len(x)):
            x = x[i:len(x)]+x[0:i]
            if int(x) not in prime_list:
                circular = False
                break
        if circular:
            prime2.append(int(x))
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer 938 is also a possible rotation

Comment: @YourAverageEuler neither is actually as circular prime because the definition is *all* rotations are primes. The number of circular primes below 1000000 is surprisingly small.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is not stopping at 71 but rather at 19.

Basically the first few prime numbers: `2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17` are all circular prime. So in the `circular_checker()` function when it goes to check `19` it tries to check whether `91` is in the list or not. Since `91` is not prime it returns `False` and exits the function.

I believe what you want to do is break out of the inner for loop and not return from the function.

This is the correct implementation of the circular function :

```
def circular_checker():
    for j in prime_list:
        x = str(j)
        isCircular = True                     #This line was changed
        for i in range(0, len(x)):
            x = x[i:len(x)]+x[0:i]
            if int(x) not in prime_list:
                isCircular = False            #This line was changed
                break                         #This line was changed
        if isCircular:                        #This line was changed
            prime2.append(int(x))
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it gives the most complete and correct explanation of the problem, but khelwood's answer is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way to do this would be to generate a set of primes as strings and check for the presence of rotated digits for each entry in the list.

First generate primes up to 1000000.  There are tons of ways to do this but the sieve of Eratosthenes is simple and fast:

```
R      = 1000000
sieve  = [True]*R
primes = set()
for n in range(2,R+1):
    if sieve[n-1]:
        primes.add(str(n))
        sieve[n*n-1::n] = [False]*len(range(n*n-1,R,n))
```

Then check for primes that have all their rotations also present in the primes list:

```
circular = []
for p in primes:
    if all(p[i:]+p[:i] in primes for i in range(len(p))):
        circular.append(p)

print(len(circular)) # number of circular primes
```